# Query returned as Boolean?

Tags: php, mysql

Can't figure out whats wrong with this.

```
$replies_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
                  FROM forum_posts
                 WHERE forum_posts.thread_id = 1";
```

I'm trying to calculate the total replies in a specific thread. I am just testing on thread_id 1 at the moment.

Error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: The query is returning as boolean giving me an error.

Comment: Please, add more details: error message, what are you trying to do, actual/expected result. Currently your problem is absolutely unclear.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: Add this to initial question.

Comment: Also, please, specify complete code of your script - looks like the problem is in it, not in SQL query.

Comment: The error message will have given you a line number. You need to post the code from and from before that line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the query failed for whatever reasons, and returned boolean FALSE, which you then passed on to the `fetch_assoc()` call. You should restructure your code like this:

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($replies_sql);
if ($stmt === FALSE) {
    die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($stmt));
}
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt);
```

never assume a database query will succeed. There's only one way to succeed, and far too many ways to fail.